# Git conflict markers

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

After I pulled from remote branch, I got conflict, when I open the file it looks something like below:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

I need some explanations of the markers, which portion of code is pulled from remote and which is from local?

What does the code `77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086` stand for?

Comment: For all other cases see: https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_merge_conflict_cheatsheet

Answer (score 855, accepted):

The line (or lines) between the lines beginning `<<<<<<<` and `======` here:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Hello world
=======
```

... is what you already had locally - you can tell because `HEAD` points to your current branch or commit.  The line (or lines) between the lines beginning `=======` and `>>>>>>>`:

```
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

... is what was introduced by the other (pulled) commit, in this case `77976da35a11`.  That is the object name (or "hash", "SHA1sum", etc.) of the commit that was merged into `HEAD`.  All objects in git, whether they're commits (version), blobs (files), trees (directories) or tags have such an object name, which identifies them uniquely based on their content.

Comment: What does the code 77976da35a11 stands for then?

Comment: 7797... is the commit you tried to merge from.

Comment: @Mellon that would be the SHA ID for the commit, where you got the changes, when you did the `pull`

Comment: Every time you make a commit - git computes a hash which is a function of the current content/code you have. So 7797 is the computed hash that depicts the commit you are merging.

Comment: is there software that knows how to render `git conflict format` and present it in two columns for merging?

Comment: Is there any way to configure this so we have meaningful labels like branch names and commit ids ? Or are we stuck forever guessing how to work around git developer madness??

Comment: Look for a 3 way merge tool. Will show 3 files - the common parent, your current branch version and the one you're pulling in side by side and highlight whats different. I use P4merge for complex conflicts - https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge

Comment: Simple and clean explanation. Beginners can refer https://help.github.com/en/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line

Comment: I did not understand what I must do

Comment: You can use tags to mark special points in the history, like releases.

Comment: for anyone looking for a more encompassing response that also covers `|||||||` markers see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156537/314780