# django error after running manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I get this wierd error after running "python manage.py runserver"
 It started after i was pushing my repo to github.
No matter where i try the command (virtualenv or system) i get the same error, just diffrent paths.

Here the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 128, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/home/moonith/Dokumenty/Python/django-justme/justme/Rango/settings.py", line 57
    <<<<<<< HEAD
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you have any ideas how to work this out?

Comment: There was a merge conflict: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657315/git-merge-left-head-marks-in-my-files

Answer (score 0):

`settings.py` has all those `<<<<<<<<<`s in there from the merge. Get them out and you should be OK.