# Switch back to stashed version git

Tags: git

I was on a branch and made some changes. I then stashed the changes to the branch and subsequently made a new branch via:

```
git stash save "message"

git checkout -b newbranch oldbranch
```

Now I want to go back to the version I was in when I stashed, how do I do that? I also didn't make any changes in the newbranch so I don't care if I lose any information from the newbranch, I will just be deleting it.

Comment: Did you try with 'git stash pop'?

Comment: If you want to create a branch from uncommited changes, you don't need to stash, `checkout -b branchname` is enough.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you mean by

> go back to the version I was in when I stashed

If you want to retrieve the stashed changes, you can use either use [`git stash pop`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt) or [`git stash apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-apply--index-q--quietltstashgt). The difference being that `pop` will remove the changes form the stash and `apply` will leave the changes in stash (i.e. so they can be applied again).

If you want to switch back to `oldbranch`, you can use [`git checkout oldbranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

---

Here's an example workflow:

```
# start a fresh repository
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/chuckx/code/stackoverflow/git-stash/.git/

# start a fresh branch
$ git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'

# populate a file with content and commit it
$ echo branch1 content > file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m "branch1 content"
[branch1 (root-commit) dadf402] branch1 content
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt

# make a post-commit change to the file
$ echo stashed content >> file.txt
$ git status
On branch branch1
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

# stash the post-commit change
$ git stash save
Saved working directory and index state WIP on branch1: dadf402 branch1 content

# verify that we're back to a clean working tree with no changes
$ git status
On branch branch1
nothing to commit, working tree clean

# start a new branch
$ git checkout -b branch2
Switched to a new branch 'branch2'

# make a change
$ echo branch2 content >> file.txt
$ git status
On branch branch2
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ cat file.txt
branch1 content
branch2 content


# decide that we do not want to commit any changes to the new branch

# switch back to the original branch
$ git checkout branch1
M       file.txt
Switched to branch 'branch1'

# notice that our unstaged changes carry over after the branch switch
$ git status
On branch branch1
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ cat file.txt
branch1 content
branch2 content


# perform a checkout of all files to fetch files as we left them in
# in the original branch
$ git checkout .
$ git status
On branch branch1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ cat file.txt
branch1 content

# retrieve the stashed changes and apply them over the fresh orignal
# branch checkout
$ git stash pop
On branch branch1
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (9a326f0ff35f65313da479c742b624870807f550)
$ cat file.txt
branch1 content
stashed content
```

Comment: How do I read the: <<<<<<< Updated upstream
=======
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
Is this whole section from the stashed changes or from the branch?

Comment: @jchaykow I'm not sure what command you've run and what you're looking at. It may be useful to update your question with more context around what you're attempting.

Comment: @jchaykow Those are [conflict markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10657351/7976758) after `git stash apply/pop`. You need to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: FYI, added an example workflow. My guess (based on my understanding of what you've described) is that you did not flush out your unstaged changes after switching back to `oldbranch` (see the `git checkout .` command in the example workflow).

Comment: Did this answer your question?