# Strange behavior from Git or editor: symbol added in a checkout?

Tags: git

I was on a branch v, then I switched to the master branch, then switched back to branch v. When I compiled again, compilation failed because a strange symbol appeared in my code:

[image]

I am using OS X Lion and latest version of textWrangler, and I am quite sure I did not add this by accident. Is this a fault of Git or textWrangler?

**UPDATE**

There is something git added after a merge:

[image]

Comment: What makes you so sure you didn't add this by accident? Git certainly did not cause this.

Comment: I hadn't noticed you updated your question. See my update below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is Git's fault. You can get characters like this by hitting `option` and a letter:

```
option+s = ß
option+b = ∫
option+c = ç
option+z = Ω
option+d = ∂
option+q = œ
```

And so on. This might simply be an accident (I hit one of those combinations everyweek).

**UPDATE**:

What you are seeing in your second example is a **conflict marker**, and Git absolutely put that there. It means, when you merged a branch into your current one (maybe a pull from github), Git could not figure out what goes where. So, instead of trying to guess which branch has the correct version, it leaves that section in a conflicted stated, indicating your local changes, and the changes introduced from the merge. This will usually happen when two people modify the same content on two different branches.

Borrowing from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901901/620197), suppose you had `file.txt`, and after merging you have a section like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt
```

Everything contained between `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======` is what you entered (this section is often labeled `local`)

Everything between `=======` and `>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086:file.txt` is what is in the same place in the incoming commit (often labeled as `remote`).

When you see this after a merge, you have to manually fix the file by removing the markers (`<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt`, `=======` and `>>>>>>> 77976da`) and decide which version you want to keep; in this case `Hello World`, `GoodBye`, or maybe you want to keep both. The point is, the same content was edited in two different branches, and Git could not figure out how to deal with those lines.

Git is an amazing version control system, but like all tools, there are limits to what it can accomplish.

A quick note about some little odd things; When I am working in Xcode, I can go to the terminal, run all the git commands I want, and go back to working to XCode right away. With **Sublime Text 2**, I have quit Sublime Text, run the git commands, then re-open Sublime Text, otherwise changes do not persist as I would have expected. I am not sure about **Text Wrangler**, you will have figure that part out (or maybe someone can leave a comment).

Some links about Git for you:

- [Git Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html)
- [Dealing with Merge Conflicts](http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html)