# Remove git comments from files

Tags: git, github

Something weird happened this morning when I did a commit. I got an error, said to pull, I then pushed and all the files with new changes now have comments such as:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
>>>>>>> d737b374ebaef4b0f7bd4e3b008e8c4740beca4c
```

They are in the repo that way. How can I recover my files without going through all of them and removing them manually?

And why the heck did this happen is a more important question. Renders the concept of versioning useless - just spent an hour cleaning this mess

Comment: Have you read the error?

Comment: Was a pretty standard one I saw before - something about unmerged changes, perform a git pull etc..

Comment: And nothing about a conflict?

Comment: Not anymore, but it merged all the comments after I pulled, push

Comment: And there is nothing between early version and versions with comments so manual remove might be the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just spent an hour cleaning this mess

It is a job [for bfg](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) then:

```
bfg --replace-text markers.txt  my-repo.git
```

With markers.txt including:

```
regex:<<<.*>>>=
```

That would get rid of all those [merge markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901864/git-conflict-markers) in no time.

BFG repo cleaner is an alternative to `git-filter-branch`.

You would need to tweak a bit if you need to keep the HEAD part only:

```
# remove just <<< line
regex:<<<.*$
# remove everything after ===
regex:===.*>>>
```

Comment: Would that leave the HEAD code intact? i.e. <<< HEAD (leave this) ==== (remove this) >>>>xxxxx

Comment: @Yashua no I have edited the answer to show how to leave HEAD and remove the rest.