# Resolve git merge conflict

Tags: git, git-merge

I tried to merge in the new changes made in master branch to my local branch. I ran the following commands:

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase master
```

After that I move on to resolve the conflicts during the rebase process.

My question here is in the conflict what does HEAD mean? It means my local branch head right?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901864/git-conflict-markers

Comment: Won't close this (yet?) but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/25576415/1256452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HEAD in git is *always* where you are. You checkout a branch? HEAD points to the tip of the branch. You checkout a revision? HEAD points to that revision.