# Get a conflict while pulling data form Bitbucket. Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, bitbucket, git

I'm getting a conflict in info.plist but when I trying to resolve I get this error "The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."
Check the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that the `Info.plist` file has an incorrect format after the pull.

Scroll to the conflict itself, there should be [conflict markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901864/git-conflict-markers). Resolve the conflicts by selecting either version of code and removing the markers.
You can also use an external editor to do that if Xcode is not allowing you to edit the file.