# Is there a way to view resolved merge conflicts on GitHub?

Tags: github

I recently resolved merge conflicts on 4 different files on the GitHub web editor. I am trying to go back and view the 4 files that had merge conflicts but I can't seem to find any merge conflict history.

Is there a way to view resolved merge conflicts on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to view resolved merge conflicts on GitHub?

No, because once resolved,  a file which had merge conflict (meaning [merge markers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7901864/6309)) no longer has those markers, and is just a regular file part of a merge commit.

You would need, in a local clone of that GitHub repository, to:

- artificially retry that merge, just to get the list of files with conflicts
- compare those files with the same file in the merge commit, to see the difference which would be the merge resolution.