# syncro file force with distant repo without merge

Tags: git, server, git-checkout, git-merge-conflict

Problem is, i have a file on server branch release who has some conflict (<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ...... ) present on file on my server (repo local) but not on git ( repo distant ).
And i don't want to modify it directly on server.
I want he take the file on github and put it on the server without conflict and properly.

I try :
1/ git checkout src/Controller/FileName.php ( but it take the file with the merge conflict comment )

And others reset, merge, .... but i don't find the good way to resolve my problem.

I just want he take the file on github ( repo distant ) and put it on server ( without the merge conflict )

Someone have an idea to resolve it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you want to check a particular file out of a particular commit, using either `git checkout` or `git restore`. See [How to retrieve a single file from a specific revision in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610208/1256452)

Answer (score 0):

No checkout should be required: simply switch to your release branch and edit the file with the [conflict markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901901/6309) (`<<<<` `====` `>>>>`)

Once you have remove them, leaving only the sections you need, add, commit and push.