# "<<<<<<< HEAD" inserts itself after commit

Tags: git

Why does "<<<<<<< HEAD" appear in my R script?

I think this refers to a Git Head, but I don't understand why it inserts itself in my code. When it inserts itself it breaks the code

Is there a way to prevent this?

```r
AllAlliancePerformance <- Tab_PercentCompliant %>% 
  filter(ClaimsAdjudicatedThrough == VBP_Report_Date) %>% 
  group_by(SubMeasureID) %>% 
  summarise(Sum_AdaptedCompliant = sum(AdaptedCompliant, na.rm = FALSE),
            Sum_TotalEligible = sum(TotalEligible, na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(Percent_Compliant = Sum_AdaptedCompliant/Sum_TotalEligible) %>%
<<<<<<< HEAD
  mutate(NCQA_Mean = NCQA_MeanList) %>% 
  mutate(PerformanceLevel = (Percent_Compliant - NCQA_Mean))
=======
  #mutate(NCQA_Mean = Tab_PercentCompliant$AdaptedNCQAMean) %>% 
  mutate(PerformanceLevel = (Percent_Compliant - AdaptedNCQAMean))
>>>>>>> 90d29b1de468129cce7530d84a5f7771c33a74c6
```

Comment: Because there's a conflict git  needs you to resolve. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7901864/3001761

Comment: Those are conflict markers. See [Resolving a merge conflict using the command line](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines that begin with "<<<<<<<", "=======" and ">>>>>>>" are `diff` markers. Chances are, there was a merge conflict in your branch. Do `git status` to find out and if so, resolve the merge conflict (edit the file selecting the correct fix) and git add it (or ignore or cancel) and allow the merge to complete.